# Material score in analysis report

Tags: engines, analysis, scid, material

Is it possible to do an analysis using Scid vs PC or any other major chess program where it shows material score after each move in addition to showing the normal evaluation score? So for an endgame of let's say a king with 2 knights vs king with a bishop the material and evaluation scores would show (6-3 +0.0) on the last move of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Check the program pgn-extract ([https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/~djb/pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/%7Edjb/pgn-extract)). It has what you probably need. Here I copy a fragment of its help:

> Include a position evaluation after each move (--evaluation)
>
> The --evaluation argument causes a comment to be appended to every move, which contains an evaluation of the position immediately following that move. The default evaluation is a simplified version of Shannon's board evaluation. In this case, the evaluation is the difference between the value of White's position and Black's, where the value of a position is a weighted sum of the pieces plus a multiplier (0.1) applied to the number of available moves for that player.
>
> I see this primarily as being a hook for people who wish to embed their own evaluations in the output. See the evaluate function in apply.c if you wish to write your own.
>
> However, an alternative approach to annotating games with engine analysis would be to consider using something like my UCI-analyser that can pass suitably formatted PGN files to a UCI-compatible engine. See, for instance, the section on obtaining annotated output in PGN format.

pgn-extract: A Portable Game Notation (PGN) Manipulator for Chess Games
Version 19-04 by David J. Barnes (@kentdjb)

Comment: Is that really the only way to do it? There is no way to add the FEN position after each move using a program's analysis report (for example, Scid vs PC's annotation feature)?

Comment: That's how I imagine it. You can modify pgn-extract source to include evaluations by an engine. That's explained by its author. 
  A program like Scid vs PC is primarily an interface to visualize a game, with some procedures added to be a tool. Does not have what you are looking. Except perhaps, that you modify an engine code and the reading of the engine result by SCID vs PC, to include the information you wants in every move.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following utility that seems to do the task in a very straightforward way:

http://www.lutanho.net/pgn/pgn2fen.html

So I ask, is it hard to code this? If so, why is it software programs don't offer this feature in their exporting options?